# Summation methods ordered by strength

Tags: sequences-and-series, order-theory, divergent-series, summation-method

A summation method is a partial function from scalar sequences to scalars, i.e. an element of the set $\mathbb{C}^\mathbb{N} \rightharpoonup \mathbb{C}$. A summation method $\Sigma_1$ is weaker than a summation method $\Sigma_2$ iff $\Sigma_1 \subseteq \Sigma_2$, i.e. $\text{dom } \Sigma_1 \subseteq \text{dom } \Sigma_2$ and $\forall a \in \text{dom } \Sigma_1 : \Sigma_1(a) = \Sigma_2(a)$. A summation method $\Sigma_1$ is consistent with a summation method $\Sigma_2$ iff $\forall a \in \text{dom } \Sigma_1 \cap \text{dom } \Sigma_2 : \Sigma_1(a) = \Sigma_2(a)$.

Cauchy summation is defined as the limit of partial sums, where such a limit exists:
\begin{align}
    (\text{Cauchy}) \sum a
    &= \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=0}^m a_n
\end{align}

A summation method is regular iff it is stronger than Cauchy summation. A summation method is linear iff $\Sigma(sa) = s\Sigma(a)$ and $\Sigma(a+b) = \Sigma(a)+\Sigma(b)$ for every scalar $s$, sequence $a$, and sequence $b$. A summation method is stable iff $\Sigma(a)=a(0)+\Sigma(\sigma(a))$, where $\sigma(a)(n)=a(n+1)$ is the shift operator. Is there a comprehensive list of summation methods (partially) ordered by strength? Are the following methods correctly ordered by strength?

\begin{align}
    (\text{Cesàro},\alpha) \sum a
    &= \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=0}^m \frac{\binom{m}{n}}{\binom{m+\alpha}{n}} a_n
    \\
    (\text{Lambert}) \sum a
    &= \lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0^+} \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=0}^m a_n \frac{\varepsilon(n+1) \mathrm{e}^{-\varepsilon(n+1)}}{1-\mathrm{e}^{-\varepsilon(n+1)}} \\
    (\text{Abelian means},\lambda) \sum a
    &= \lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0^+} \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=0}^m a_n \exp(-\varepsilon \lambda_n)
    \\
    (\text{Borel},\alpha) \sum a
    &= \int_0^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-t} \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=0}^m \frac{a_n t^{n\alpha}}{(n\alpha)!} \,\mathrm{d}t
\end{align}

Note that Abel and Lindelöf summation are Abelian means summation for $\lambda_n = n$ and $\lambda_n = n \log n$, respectively. Do the following methods fall somewhere in the linear order above?

\begin{align}
    (\text{Le Roy}) \sum a
    &= \lim_{z \rightarrow 1^-} \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=0}^m \frac{(zn)!}{n!} a_n
    \\
    (\text{Mittag-Leffler}) \sum a
    &= \lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0} \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=0}^m \frac{a_n}{(\varepsilon n)!}
\end{align}

Comment: It appears the generalized Borel summation is also called [Mittag-Leffler summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler_summation).

Comment: Note: I've extended this question to the limits themselves [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3298993/generalized-limits).